# Automatically re-running a SQL query with different parameters

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query, which allows me to identify the number of times an individual conducts a transaction of at least $1,000 exactly twice in a seven-day period:

```
select count(*)
from (

select id, date, visit_count, daily_total_amount,
sum(visit_count) over (partition by id order by date range between interval '6' day preceding and current row) as rolling_visit_sum
from (

select id, date, count(*) as visit_count, sum(total_amount) as daily_total_amount
from (

select id, date, time, store, sum(currency_amount) as total_amount
from table
group by id, date, time, store
having sum(currency_amount) >= 1000

)
group by id, date
order by id, date

)
group by id, date, visit_count, daily_total_amount

)
where rolling_visit_sum = 2;
```

I would like to re-run the query to see how the results change as I change the parameters (using [$1000, $2000, $3000, $4000, $5000, $6000, $7000, $8000, $9000] as the minimum **sum(currency_amount)** threshold and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] as the requisite **rolling_visit_sum**). I imagine this can be automated with a loop of some sort, but I am new at this and confused myself when I tried to search how to do this myself.

Ideally I would end up with an output table something like the following (with the **x**'s populated with the query results:

```
sum(currency_amount) |  rolling_visit_sum  | count(*)
    1000                    1                    x
    1000                    2                    x
    1000                    3                    x
    1000                    4                    x
    1000                    5                    x
    1000                    6                    x
    2000                    1                    x
    2000                    2                    x
    2000                    3                    x
    2000                    4                    x
```

.......

```
sum(currency_amount) |  rolling_visit_sum  | count(*)
    9000                    3                    x
    9000                    4                    x
    9000                    5                    x
    9000                    6                    x
```

The actual format of the results does not matter a whole lot as long as I am able to distinguish the results for each combination of parameters. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how you could do it in T-SQL, maybe it helps you (even I assume you use oracle but oracle does have similar logic to cursors). You could also use a normal oracle loop statement (a lot of examples in google available).

```
-- declare variables

declare @ParamterCurrencyAmount numeric(26, 2),
        @ParameterRollingVisitSum int


-- declare table variable

declare @CurrencyAmounts table
(
    CurrencyAmount numeric(26, 2)
)

-- declare table variable

declare @RollingVisitSums table
(
    RollingVisitSum int
)


-- insert sample data 

insert into @CurrencyAmounts
(
    CurrencyAmount
)
select 1000 union all
select 2000 union all
select 3000 union all
select 4000 union all
select 5000 union all
select 6000 union all
select 8000 union all
select 9000

insert into @RollingVisitSums
(
    RollingVisitSum
)
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6



-- join the data together for a cursor and loop through the cursor

declare ParameterCursor cursor local static read_only forward_only for 
select CurrencyAmounts.CurrencyAmount,
RollingVisitSums.RollingVisitSum
from @CurrencyAmounts CurrencyAmounts,
@RollingVisitSums RollingVisitSums

open ParameterCursor 
fetch next from ParameterCursor  

into @ParamterCurrencyAmount, @ParameterRollingVisitSum

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin


    print @ParamterCurrencyAmount
    print @ParameterRollingVisitSum


    -- do your code here whatever you wanna do with your parameters



    fetch next from ParameterCursor 
    into @ParamterCurrencyAmount, @ParameterRollingVisitSum

end 


close ParameterCursor;
deallocate ParameterCursor;
```